# Openwrt ipv6 firewall forwarding

Tags: networking, router, firewall, ipv6, openwrt

I hope you can help me with following problem. I'm trying to connect from my vServer to my local IPv6 machine. I want to configure guacamole on my vServer to connect to this client with open port 3389. But i cant get any traffic from wan to my local machine, not even icmp.

vserver (guacamole) --> client in my lan with ipv6 and open port 3389

I already tried to set the firewall rule in openwrt to allow all traffic from wan to lan but that didnt work either.

My thought was that i can directly connect to the ipv6 client in my lan

I hope some of you can help me out :)

Thanks allot.